# Format a numeric cell with Jakarta POI using Locale

Tags: format, apache-poi

Hy,

I need to set a format for a numeric cell(decimal separator....) in excel using Jakarta POI and a Locale. What I need is find a method which formats a numeric cell in excel without having to specify a hardcoded format like #,##0.000", just a Locale(I think Java already internally uses specific formats for numerics values according to a Locale). Is there one?

For example, what I **do not need** is the next(because here its specifying a hardcoded format):

```
cellStyle.setDataFormat(hssfDataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.000"));
```

Thanks

Comment: It hasn't been called Jakarta POI for years and years and years... What happens if you upgrade to a version of *Apache POI* from this decade?

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer, I will try what you suggest!